# How to apply an "interface" method to a set of rows in kdb?

Tags: kdb

Sorry if this is a newbie question again.

I am trying to replicate the functionality of interfaces as seen in c++, rust etc. in kdb as is shown in a simple demonstration below:

```
q).iface.a.fun:{x*y+z}
q).iface.b.fun:{x*x+y+z}
q)ifaces:`a`b; // for demonstration purposes
q)tab:([]time:`datetime$();kind:`ifaces$();x:`long$();y:`long$();z:`long$());
q)n:10;
q)tab,:flip(n#.z.z;n?ifaces;n?10;n?10;n?10)
```

Now you would assume that the `kind` would be able to reference the `` `a`b `` `fun` methods of the `iface` interface as follows:

```
q)?[`tab;();0b;`max`ifaceval!((max;`x);(`.iface;`kind;`fun;`x;`y;`z))] 
evaluation error:

fun

  [0]  ?[`tab;();0b;`max`ifaceval!((max;`x);(`.iface;`kind;`fun;`x;`y;`z))]
       ^
```

Obviously the functional nature of the select inhibits referencing the `fun` method on account of the symbol type field declarations.
You can avert this error by using `enlist` as follows:

```
q)?[`tab;();0b;`max`ifaceval!((max;`x);(`.iface;`kind;enlist`fun;`x;`y;`z))] 
max ifaceval                                                                    ..
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------..
9   77 154 95 65 0 128 153 126 60 49 77 154 95 65 0 128 153 126 60 49 77 154 ..
```

However this duplicates the result of `fun` for each row.
How might one effectively go about this without getting the above malformed responses?
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting `ifaceval` first will ensure each row is returned. `max x` is a scalar, which forces all the `ifaceval` entries into one row. The scalar will be expanded across all rows if a vector column precedes it.

```
q)?[`tab;();0b;`ifaceval`max!((`.iface;`kind;enlist`fun;`x;`y;`z);(max;`x))]
ifaceval                          max
-------------------------------------
160 11 126 28 32 60 76 10 112 168 8
96  10 77  24 16 35 60 6  63  104 8
96  10 77  24 16 35 60 6  63  104 8
96  10 77  24 16 35 60 6  63  104 8
96  10 77  24 16 35 60 6  63  104 8
160 11 126 28 32 60 76 10 112 168 8
96  10 77  24 16 35 60 6  63  104 8
160 11 126 28 32 60 76 10 112 168 8
160 11 126 28 32 60 76 10 112 168 8
160 11 126 28 32 60 76 10 112 168 8
```

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for though. If you want to calculate `ifaceval` for *each* row in the table, this should work.

```
q)?[tab;();0b;`ifaceval`max!(((';(`.iface;::;enlist`fun));`kind;`x;`y;`z);(max;`x))]
ifaceval max
------------
160      8
10       8
77       8
24       8
16       8
60       8
60       8
10       8
112      8
168      8
```

One point to make is that it's probably best to avoid using kdb keywords for column names. Although it works in functional queries, it does not for qSQL ones.

```
q)select max:max x from tab
'assign
  [0]  select max:max x from tab
                 ^
```

Comment: Nice! Can shave a few characters with ```?[tab;();0b;`ifacevalue`max!((`.iface';`kind;1#`fun;`x;`y;`z);(max;`x))]```

Comment: Hi Cathal, thanks for the response. Sorry for the silly mistake of using max as a column name.